# Creating one aligned vector of floats in c

Tags: c, memory, vector

I'm working in a project using SIMD instructions and I don´t know exactly how to create a vector aligned in memory. I´m using packets of 128 bits (4 floats per packet).

```
float redVector[vectorSize];
```

I saw many places where people use structures and the property attribute... Any explanation is welcomed. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your compiler supports C11, you can use [`_Alignas()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas):

```
_Alignas(16) float redVector[vectorSize];
```

Some people prefer the more C++ compatible

```
#include <stdalign.h>

alignas(16) float redVector[vectorSize];
```

Pre C11 gcc can use

```
float redVector[vectorSize] __attribute__((__aligned__(16)));
```